# PrimeNg FilterService

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, frontend

I need to customize this property of the p-columnFilter component, but I can't find the way, could you help me,

[image: 1]

In the ts I have it this way to be able to modify the filter modes and place the names in a personalized way, but for the no filter I can't get that option, has anyone found a solution to this?

```
 this.matchModeOptions = [
      { label: "Iguales", value: customFilterName },
      { label: "Comienza con", value: FilterMatchMode.STARTS_WITH }
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

By `PrimeNGConfig` get `setTranslation()` to use to customize label name;

```
import { PrimeNGConfig } from 'primeng/api';

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    ...,
    private config: PrimeNGConfig
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.config.setTranslation({
      noFilter: 'MyNoFilter',
    });
    ...
  }
}
```

Example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablefilter-demo-bzjnad?file=src/app/app.component.ts)